# Parent Div not wrapping around its child divs - Missing clearFloat may be the issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small issue with one of my divs the #divSidebar not wrapping around it's child divs. It's probably something small that I probably overlooked, but I've been fussing with it for quite sometime. I believe it has something to do with a missing . I can get the content over to the side, but I had to add a innerSideBar div that was floated to the right.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<title>Welcome to TutorialHelp!</title>
<link href="css/tutorialHelp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="divHeaderContainer">
<div id="divHeader">
<div id="divLogo"></div>
<div id="divNavigtation">
<div id="divNavMenu">
<ul>
<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="Tutorials/index.html">Tutorials</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="Photoshop/index.html">Photoshop</a>
<li><a href="Dreamweaver/index.html">Dreamweaver</a>
<li><a href="Illustrator/index.html">Illustrator</a>
<li><a href="Flash/index.html">Flash</a>
<li><a href="InDesign/index.html">InDesign</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="Articles/index.html">Articles</a></li>
<li><a href="About/index.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="Contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul> <!-- end main UL -->
<br class="clearFloat" />
</div>
<div id="divSocial"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="divContentContainer">
<div id="divWrapper">
<div id="divInnerWrapper">
<div id="divContent">
<div id="divBanner"></div>
<div id="divListing">
<header class="listing">
<div id="divListingLeft">
<a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="images/photoshopBasicsImage.jpg" alt="PhotoshopBasicsImage" title="PhotoshopBasicsImage" />
</a>
<span class="metaWrapper">Photoshop</span>
<span class="metaWrapper">Beginner</span>
</div>
<div id="divListingRight">
<p class="tags">
<a href="#" title="Link to the Tutorials Page">Tutorials</a>
>>
<a href="#" title="Link to the Photoshop Page">Photoshop</a>
</p>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<p class="date">
Posted on: October 16, 2012 by 
</p>
<h1><a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">The Basics Of Photoshop</a></h1>
<div id="synopsis"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis viverra lacus. Ut volutpat augue nec nulla sodales facilisis. Duis magna mauris, auctor a hendrerit vitae, adipiscing vel ante. Praesent risus elit, egestas a commodo non, suscipit id mauris. Ut ligula velit, tempor vel accumsan sed, sollicitudin quis sem. Integer nunc sem, feugiat non luctus ut, varius quis enim. Curabitur non odio id leo lobortis gravida acac arcu.</p></div>
</div>
<br class="clearFloat" /></header>
</header>
</div>
<div id="divListing">
<header class="listing">
<div id="divListingLeft">
<a href="#" title="Building A Basic Web Page In Dreamweaver">
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="images/dreamweaverBasicWebPageImage.jpg" alt="DreamweaverBasicWebPageImage" title="DreamweaverBasicWebPageImage" />
</a>
<span class="metaWrapper">Dreamweaver</span>
<span class="metaWrapper">Beginner</span>
</div>
<div id="divListingRight">
<p class="tags">
<a href="#" title="Link to the Tutorials Page">Tutorials</a>
>>
<a href="#" title="Link to the Photoshop Page">Dreamweaver</a>
</p>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<p class="date">
Posted on: October 16, 2012 by 
</p>
<h1><a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">Building A Basic Web Page In Dreamweaver</a></h1>
<div id="synopsis"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis viverra lacus. Ut volutpat augue nec nulla sodales facilisis. Duis magna mauris, auctor a hendrerit vitae, adipiscing vel ante. Praesent risus elit, egestas a commodo non, suscipit id mauris. Ut ligula velit, tempor vel accumsan sed, sollicitudin quis sem. Integer nunc sem, feugiat non luctus ut, varius quis enim. Curabitur non odio id leo lobortis gravida acac arcu.</p></div>
</div>
<br class="clearFloat" /></header>
</header>
</div>
<div id="divListing">
<header class="listing">
<div id="divListingLeft">
<a href="#" title="Designing A Cartoon Environment">
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="images/flashCartoonEnvironmentImage.png" alt="FlashCartoonEnvironmentImage" title="FlashCartoonEnvironmentImage" />
</a>
<span class="metaWrapper">Flash</span>
<span class="metaWrapper">Beginner</span>
</div>
<div id="divListingRight">
<p class="tags">
<a href="#" title="Link to the Tutorials Page">Tutorials</a>
>>
<a href="#" title="Link to the Photoshop Page">Flash</a>
</p>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
<p class="date">
Posted on: October 16, 2012 by 
</p>
<h1><a href="#" title="The Basics Of Photoshop">Designing A Cartoon Environment</a></h1>
<div id="synopsis"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis viverra lacus. Ut volutpat augue nec nulla sodales facilisis. Duis magna mauris, auctor a hendrerit vitae, adipiscing vel ante. Praesent risus elit, egestas a commodo non, suscipit id mauris. Ut ligula velit, tempor vel accumsan sed, sollicitudin quis sem. Integer nunc sem, feugiat non luctus ut, varius quis enim. Curabitur non odio id leo lobortis gravida acac arcu.</p></div>
</div>
<br class="clearFloat" /></header>
</header>
</div>
<div id="divBottomBanner"></div>
</div>
<div id="divSidebar">
<div id="divInnerSideBar">
<div id="divAdWrapper">
<div class="adListing">Advertise Here</div>
<div class="adListing">Advertise Here</div>
<div class="adListing">Advertise Here</div> 
<br class="clearFloat" />  
</div>
<fb:comments href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Tutorialhelp/497024140318879"
num_posts="4" width="300"></fb:comments>
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Tutorialhelp/497024140318879" send="true" width="285" show_faces="true" font="verdana"></fb:like>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    min-width:1300px;
    background-color:#83ACBC;
}

#divHeaderContainer{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#CEDBD9;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#divHeader{
    width:1120px;
    height:200px;
    min-width:1120px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundImage_r1_c1_r1_c1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

#divLogo{
    height:130px;

}

#divNavigation{
    height:32px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#333;
    width:1120px;
}

#divNavMenu {
    width:auto;
    height:32px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#divNavMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}

#divNavMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#DCE4E3;
}

#divNavMenu ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    height:30px;
    width:148px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #C5D1D0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#divNavMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:32px;
}

#divNavMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:9999; 
}

#divNavMenu li:hover {
   background:#83ACBC;
}

#divNavMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#9EBECB;
}

#divNavMenu a:hover {   
    color:#FFF;
} 

/* Contains the Float */

.clearFloat {
    clear:both; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* IE7 Display Fix */  

#divNavMenu ul li {

    display: inline;     

}   

#divContentContainer{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundImage_r1_c1_r3_c1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

#divWrapper{
    width:1120px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-image: url(../images/backgroundImage_r1_c1_r2_c1.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
}

#divInnerWrapper{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1088px;
}

#divContent{
    width:738px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#divBanner{
    width:700px;
    height:60px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#D3DCDA;
}

#divListing{
    padding:20px 20px 0px 18px;
    margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.listing{
    height:auto;
    background:none;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #B7B7B7;
}

#divListingLeft{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

#divListingRight{
    width:480px;
    float:right;
}

.metaWrapper{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
}

.tags{
    font-style:italic;
}

.date{
    font-style:italic;
}

#divContent #divListing p{
    padding:0 20px 0px 10px;
}

#divContent #divListing h1{
    font-size:26px;
    color:#000;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 10px;
    margin:0px;
}

h1 a{
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

#divBottomBanner{
    width:700px;
    height:60px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    margin-top:35px;
    background-color:#D3DCDA;
}

h2{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    margin:30px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #B7B7B7;
}

#contactForm{
    padding:0px;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#divSidebar{

}

#divInnerSideBar{
    width:300px;
    float:right;

}

#divAdWrapper{
    width:260px;
    height:auto;
}

.adListing{
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    background-color:#D3DCDA;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    margin: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}
```

I've added both html and css code and hopefully that will help you see where the problem is in the code. Any other problems with the code can be brought up, but looking for a solution to the #divSidebar and its child content.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `divSidebar`

```
#divSidebar{
float:right;
}
```

***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/MKsMU/)***

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had floated that div before, but I think it was affected because I also had a set width to it before.

#divSideBar{
float:right;
width:300px;
}

was before I saved it, but it caused problems.

Comment: or   -  display:inline-block;